# X11 unable to maximize applications when no window manager is used

Tags: x11

We have a Linux based system that does not use a Window manager.  When we start certain applications (for instance Firefox) from a terminal window (e.g. Firefox &) we find that no matter what we do, we can't get the application to display full screen.

If we run xrandr, it shows the default resolution is 1280x1024, but when we try to maximize Firefox (by pressing F11) the application is only sized to 1203x650.

Another application that seems to have the same problem is the evince PDF reader.

Our application is not configured to run a window manager (and we don't want to add one), so I'm wondering if there is something else that we can do to get these applications to render full screen.

Thanks...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Although you don't **want** to use a window manager, you might **need** to use a window manager.

I haven't dug into the X server sources around this, so I can't definitively say X requires a window manager to run properly. But as somebody who writes X client code, and hacks the X server, on minimalist embedded devices with small screens, low CPU power and no GPU... let's just say, all the major players in that space use one, and have good reasons for it.

If you want to avoid chewing up a lot of disk space, RAM or CPU power doing window management, you should check out [matchbox](http://matchbox-project.org/). It's a low-footprint window manager designed to meet those criteria, and it's what many folks in that minimalist embedded space are using. My employer uses it on cell phones, configured so that only one app at a time is visible to the user, and the foreground app takes up the whole screen with no window borders. But you can use it other ways, too - Nokia uses it for their Maemo-based network tablets.

Answer (score 8):

You could use `xwit(1)` to forcibly resize and place the windows.  But as as far as I know, X11 in itself *does not have the concept* of a "maximized" window; the very idea is only added by most window managers and/or applications (like Firefox).

Answer (score 3):

Does passing the "-geometry=1280x1024+0+0" option to Firefox help?

Comment: The geometry switch did not do the trick for Firefox, and was not recognized by the evince PDF reader (see the update to my question above).  I'm sure that there is something fundamental that I'm mssing, I'm just not sure what it is.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, also... if you don't explicitly set a window manager, you might be unexpectedly falling back to [the default X11 window manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twm). If you're not absolutely positive there's no window manager, you should check into this possibility.

Comment: `twm` has rather obvious window title bars and buttons, so I should think anyone would know they were running a window manager.  It also, in its default configuration, forces the user to *place windows as they are created* before showing any new window, which should be an dead givaway.

Comment: our .xinitrc is configured to just start an xterm, no window manager at all.  We do, on occasion, start twm from the xterm, but I'm confident that twm is not starting when we initialize X.

Thanks for the suggestion...